# JQuery - Else not running function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run a function, if an IF statement is false.

My code is...

```
 $('#finartwork').mousedown(function(){
      if (uploadqty = 1) { 
          if ($.trim($('.artwork1').val()).length == 0) {
             alert('Please select your artwork')
          }
      } else { 
          processcartitem(); 
      } 
 });

    function processcartitem() {
         $('#artworkcontainer').slideUp(500,function() {
                $('#addontable').css('background-color','<?php echo $col ?>');
                $('#addontable').css('color','#fff');
                $('#artworktable').css('background-color','#e1e2e4');
                $('#artworktable').css('color','#333');
                $('#addoncontainer').slideDown(500);
        }); 
        $("#productvariation").click();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
Lewis

Answer (score 5):

```
if (uploadqty = 1)
```

always evaluates to true.

If you want to check the value of 'uploadqty', use == or ===

Comment: I appreciate your help, however - changing this breaks the code is the argument is true. It does nothing when using ==

Comment: What is the expected value for 'uploadqty'?

Comment: 1, 2 or 3. It will be based on a number which the user selects earlier.

Comment: if `(uploadqty >= 1 && uploadqty <=3)` will check for all acceptable values of 'uploadqty'

Comment: Well, I was hoping to run different functions if 1 or 2...but havent got this far.

Comment: Sorry - posted that too early. I think it is because the var is set onmousedown earlier on in the page. So it seems it cannot get the value of the var

Comment: When I simply try to alert(uploadqty) it doesnt do anything

Comment: if you want to check for multiple distinct values, consider using the [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) construct. If you can provide a code sample on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it would easier to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with equal sign it should be ==